# TextInputType.number incorrectly shows sign decimal buttons

Tags: flutter

According to the docs, `TextInputType.number` should show a keyboard without sign and decimal buttons, like this:

[image]

But when I call

```
TextField(
  :
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
```

I get the keyboard:

[image]

I tried below with the same results

```
TextField(
  :
  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: false, decimal: false),
```

Comment: which keyboard you want? 1st image or 2nd image

Comment: I want the the top image

Answer (score 0):

Lots of search I have found one package for that Try to use [**`keyboard_actions`**](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions) package, hope its helpful to you.